# How to truss a chicken?

Tags: chicken, roasting, poultry

I have seen many videos online and by chefs on tv, showing how to truss a chicken. What is your way of trussing a chicken? They all seem to have a different technique, and I am interested in a possible easier method.

Answer (score 4):

Thomas Keller's Ad Hoc Cookbook (one of the best cookbooks I've seen) recommends the following:

1. Place the chicken with the legs towards you.  Tuck the wing tips under the bird.  Cut a piece of chicken twine about 3 feet long and center it under the neck of the breast.  Pull the twine up over the breast towards you.
2. Knot the twine, pulling it tight to plump the breast.
3. Bring the ends of the twine around the ends of the drumsticks and straight up.
4. Tie as before to pull the ends of the drumsticks together and form a compatct bird.  Then tie again to secure the knot.

Answer (score 4):

I am not very good at interpreting written instructions into something visual... so in case there's anyone else out there like me, here's a video:

http://www.foodnetwork.com/videos/how-to-truss-a-turkey/27751.html

This video is Alton Brown's method, as shown on the Food Network. It's a method that has worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I like this one:

http://ruhlman.com/2010/07/how-to-truss-a-chicken.html

It's simple... and entertaining.